# How to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity with an old web forms project?

Tags: webforms, membership-provider, asp.net-core-identity

I have an old web forms application that uses membership provider. I want to use an existing .net core identity project instead of membership provider. Where and how can I configure it in my old web forms project? Does anyone know how to implement that in my old project?

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/78) contains useful information. It is based on IdentityServer3, but I think it is close to what you are looking for.